# MSSQL - set limit for a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, limit

I have a table named Test with the following columns.

```
id PK, int, not null
amount money, not null
```

I want to set a limit on the amount, say, 1000. I don't want anyone to insert a value greater than 1000 in this column. Can anyone help me on how to do this?

Comment: Read on [`Check Constraints`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
CREATE TABLE tablename
(
-------
--------
amount money,
CONSTRAINT chk_amount CHECK (amount <= 1000)
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to take the limit value, 1000 here from a table?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a check constraint, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Test
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_money CHECK (amount<=1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create check constraint for your table.

```
alter table dbo.Your_Table with check add constraint your_Table_Amount check (Amount <= 1000)
go
alter table dbo.Your_Table check constraint your_Table_Amount
```